# How to refer the index of result in a jQuery operation without writing an explicit for loop?

Tags: jquery

I would like to refer and use the index of the element in jQuery operation.

Something like this:

```
$('a').attr('data-index', ?magic?);
```

The expected result is would be:

```
<a data-index='0' ....>....</a>
<a data-index='1' ....>....</a>
//....
<a data-index='length-1' ....>....</a>
```

Although it is trivial how to do this with an explicit for loop, I was just wondering if there is a more effective way.

Comment: to noname: please do not think that you can imagine all scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing of elements is not really needed to put into attributes since you can get index easily from dom collections either in loops or using [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method

i would suggest not adding the attribute as it can change with any dom manipulation and throw off all those attribute values

```
var $links = $('a');

$links.click(function(){
  alert( $links.index(this) );
});

$links.each(function(index){
   console.log(index);
});

$links.text(function(index, oldText){
   return oldText + ' my index is ' + index;
});
```

Comment: it is really needed. By other library code an event handler will be installed on all elements. When the event fireing the only thing it will know what was the DOM object on which it fired. There I must know the index, so the only option to store it as data in the DOM object.

Comment: $links is not available in that event, neither re-queriable. It is not guarantied that the dom still contains all the link (or anything else, like: li elements). Only the links.each(function(index) will do it, and I can use then it the .attr.

Comment: No but you can gather that collection inside the event handler. It's up to you but if as you say you will be adding or removing the indexing is going to change in which case using index may not benefit you at all depending on use case

Comment: again: when the even will fire, it is not guaranteed the all elements exist. Requerying with the same query will give false index.

Comment: Ok..do what you feel works. I'm not sure if you are expecting more from this discussion or not? If there is still a problem it is not clear to me what it is without more details

Comment: All OK, links.each(function(index) answers my question. Thx